# setActualDefaultRingtoneUri reboots phone

Tags: android, ringtone

I use this code to set the Default ringtone for calls:

```
RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(MyContext, RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE, RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE));
```

It is very simple but it reboots my phone. I have tested in 2 devices using `Android 4.2.1`

If I set a differen ringtone the it works. It just happens if I use:

```
getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE)
```

Any help?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
Uri default_sound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(this, default_sound);
```

This works fine for me!

Comment: But, how do you set "setActualDefaultRingtoneUri" I don't want the tone to use it right now. I want to tell the System to start using the default ringtone.

Comment: Have you given app permission in your Manifest?

Comment: Yes of course. It works great with other ringtones. it is just the Default one.